# Flask SQLAlchemy connection

Tags: python, sql, flask, connection, database-connection

I am using sqlite3 in my Flask application. My main.py file sits inside a folder called App. Inside App I have a folder called db which is where my db is stored.

I was using the absolute path to connect to the db while I built out the app as I couldnt get Flask to connect to the db using the relative path.

I have tried every way possible.

Currently it is:

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite:///db/App.db"

But this isnt working.

Any suggestion on how to correctly set up the relative path so it can work on any machine?

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestion on how to correctly set up the relative path so it can
> work on any machine?

I suggest to use [`os.path.abspath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) to convert relative path into absolute path, then use it to build URI. For example if I would need `file://` URI for `file.txt` inside `dir` I could do

```
import os
uri = 'file://' + os.path.abspath(os.path.join('dir', 'file.txt'))
```